# Flutter flutter_html: 'EdgeInsets' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Margins?' and 'HtmlPaddings?'

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I recently upgrade to flutter_html^3.0.0-beta.2 and having these issues. In previous version, I'm able to use `EdgeInsets` for `margin` and `padding` for `Style` but in latest version `EdgeInsets` no longer works.

Old codes:

```
class HTMLContent extends StatelessWidget {
  final String htmlCode;

   HTMLContent({required this.htmlCode});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Html(
      data: htmlCode,
      style: {
        "p": Style(
          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          fontSize: pFontSize,
          fontFamily: 'Lato',
          textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
          lineHeight: const LineHeight(1.3),
        ),
        "th": Style(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6),
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight,
          color: Colors.white,
          fontFamily: 'Lato',
          fontSize: const FontSize(16),
        ),
```

For `margin`, error given: The argument type 'EdgeInsets' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Margins?'.

For `padding`, error given: The argument type 'EdgeInsets' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'HtmlPaddings?'.

[image]

I have tried to set the `margin` as `margin: Margins(bottom: 10.0),` but it doesn't work either as `margin` is a `Margins` class which takes `Margin` in its argument instead of double. Similarly, `padding` is a `HtmlPaddings` class which uses `HtmlPadding` instead of double.

[image]

Appreciate your advice. I've taken 2 years break from coding and still trying to refresh my brain. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the breaking changes that were introduced in the new update of `flutter_html`.

The [`Margins`](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_html/3.0.0-beta.2/flutter_html/Margins-class.html) class has similar named constructors with `EdgeInsets`, so you can use this for example:

```dart
margin: Margins.only(bottom: 10.0)
```

The other named constructors that you can use is `Margins.all(...)` and `Margins.symmetric(...)`.

The same goes for [`HtmlPaddings`](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_html/3.0.0-beta.2/flutter_html/HtmlPaddings-class.html).

Comment: Thank you @dhafin-rayhan. Your solutions works perfectly, example: `margin: Margins.only(bottom: 10.0)` and `padding: HtmlPaddings.all(6)`